# Use an old Nintendo NES Controller as an input device

Tags: pinout

Does anyone have a pinout diagram for the Nintendo NES Controller? I'd like to connect the NES controller to an Arduino.

Comment: unless you want to try sourcing the mating connector for that unusual NES plug, why worry about the pinout? I'd probably cut the original plug off and replace it with a DB-9, and wire it to suit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PinoutsGuide have a page [Nintendo NES and SNES joystick controller pinout](http://pinoutsguide.com/Game/snescontroller_pinout.shtml).

Answer (score 7):

The [NES Pad library](http://code.google.com/p/nespad/) not only has a pinout, but is a great arduino class for using the NES controller.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another [page with some helpful information](http://www.mit.edu/~tarvizo/nes-controller.html), including a signal diagram.

```
          +----> Power  (white)
          |
5 +---------+  7    
  | x  x  o   \     
  | o  o  o  o |    
4 +------------+ 1  
    |  |  |  |
    |  |  |  +-> Ground (brown)
    |  |  +----> Pulse  (red)
    |  +-------> Latch  (orange)
    +----------> Data   (yellow)
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a great article on [Hack-A-Day](http://hackaday.com/2010/09/02/using-an-nes-controller-on-an-android-phone/) regaring your quest.  This article is on interfacing the SNES controller with an Android utilizing an Arduino.  To save you some of the trouble of sifting through the article, I found the linked code they cited:

> This code uses an old-school 1980's
>   NES controller to control a servo and
>   an LED with the Arduino.   With this
>   code, the 'up' pad turns a servo to
>   180 degrees, 'right' turns it to 90,
>   and 'down' turns it to 0 degrees. 
>   Also, the A and B buttons turn a LED
>   on and off.   You can get a NES
>   controller from ebay for less than
>   $10.00 Here is a crude drawing of the
>   controller plug, four holes on one
>   side, three holes on the other.
>
> ---
>
> ```
>                        0     --  0v (ground)
>       +5V  ---  0      0     --CLOCK   
>   nothing  ---  0      0     --LATCH  
>   nothing  ---  0      0     --SERIAL OUT
> ```
>
> ---
>
> You can just stick wires into the
>   controller plug holes for prototyping.
>   The +5 is connected to the Arduino +5
>   Ground to Arduino Ground Latch goes to
>   Pin 2 (with this code) Clock to Pin 3
>   Serial Out to Pin 4
>
> The servo data line is connected to
>   Pin 10, and the LED is on Pin 11.
>
> If you want to see the controller
>   input on the serial monitor then just
>   open up the serial monitor.  It will
>   show you the binary numbers that are
>   coming in from the controller.   Each
>   button has its own binary number. 
>   'Up' is 11110111, for example.   I
>   included a //hidden Serial.println
>   code that will display "Button has
>   been pressed" if you press down the
>   start button.  Just erase the '//' if
>   you want to use that.   The SNES plug
>   is different, you're interested in
>   that you will have to look elsewhere
>   for the clock,latch,serial out info.
>
> Quote:
>
> ```
> /* INITIALIZATION */
> #include <ServoTimer1.h>
> ServoTimer1 servo1;
>
> int latch = 2; // set the latch pin
> int clock = 3; // set the clock pin
> int datin = 4;// set the data in pin
> byte controller_data = 0;
> int ledpin = 11;
>
>
> /* SETUP */
> void setup() {
> Serial.begin(57600);
> pinMode(latch,OUTPUT);
> pinMode(clock,OUTPUT);
> pinMode(datin,INPUT);
> pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
>
> digitalWrite(latch,HIGH);
> digitalWrite(clock,HIGH);
>
> servo1.attach(10);
>
> }
>
> /* THIS READS DATA FROM THE CONTROLLER */
> void controllerRead() {
> controller_data = 0;
> digitalWrite(latch,LOW);
> digitalWrite(clock,LOW);
>
> digitalWrite(latch,HIGH);
> delayMicroseconds(2);
> digitalWrite(latch,LOW);
>
> controller_data = digitalRead(datin);
>
> for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i ++) {
> digitalWrite(clock,HIGH);
> delayMicroseconds(2);
> controller_data = controller_data << 1;
> controller_data = controller_data + digitalRead(datin) ;
> delayMicroseconds(4);
> digitalWrite(clock,LOW);
> }
>
> }
>
> /* THE LED, SERVO, AND SERIAL MONITOR PROGRAM */
> void loop() {
> controllerRead();
> Serial.println(controller_data, BIN);
>
> // if (controller_data==B11101111){
>   // Serial.println("Button has been Pressed");   
>    //}  else {
>    //Serial.println("Button not pressed");
>    //}
>
> //for REFERENCE:  
> //UP = 11110111
> //DOWN=11111011
> //LEFT=11111101
> //RIGHT=11111110
> //SELECT=11011111
> //START=11101111
> //A=01111111
> //B=10111111
>
> if (controller_data==B01111111){
>  digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);   
>  }
>
> if (controller_data==B10111111){
>  digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);
> }
>
> if (controller_data==B11110111){
>  servo1.write(180);
> }  
>
> if (controller_data==B11111011){
>  servo1.write(0);
> }
>
> if (controller_data==B11111110){
>  servo1.write(90);
> }
>
> delay(100);
> }
> ```

[Arduino SNES Instructable](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1254964306/0#0)